# "Cannot find ContentPlaceHolder" error when anonymous access enabled

Tags: 2007, anonymous-authentication, error, master-page

I have a custom master page, custom.master, for a publishing site.  It was working fine, however I just enabled anonymous access to the publishing site, and now browsing to the home page for that site brings up the following error:

> Cannot find ContentPlaceHolder 'PlaceHolderTopBanner' in the master page '/_catalogs/masterpage/custom.master', verify content control's ContentPlaceHolderID attribute in the content page.

I started from a minimal master page for custom.master.  PlaceHolderTopBanner is a custom ContentPlaceHolder that I created (as an area for a different banner image to go on each page.)

If I disable anonymous access again, forcing me to log in before accessing the page, there are no errors and the page loads fine.

To enable anonymous access I enabled it at the web application level, and then for the publishing site -- I chose anonymous access for 'entire site'.

I guess it must be a permissions thing, but I have no clue as to what!  Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked-in and **published** the custom master page?

Comment: yep, that's probably it